# Correct way to add a comments to existing view rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, comments

I have a rails application wih a scaffold that displays images via the controllers show action. I want to add a comments for every picture. What is the right way to do this? I tried making a second controller+model+view, rendered the comments form partial in the images show view and passed the image id via a parameter. It works, but I don't think this is how it's supposed to be done. If you know a good example project that implements aomething like this please send it to me, i couldn't find anything. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can't see any problem with the way you did it. Pls add code snippets for more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically handled by [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :images do #-> url.com/images/:id
   resources :comments, only: [:create, :update, :destroy] #-> url.com/images/:image_id/comments
end

#app/controllers/images_controller.rb
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @image = Image.find params[:id]
      @comment = @image.comments.new
   end
end

#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
   def create
      @image = Image.find params[:image_id]
      @comment = @image.comments.new comment_params
      redirect_to @image if @comment.save
   end

   private

   def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
   end
end
```

You'll be able to show the views as follows:

```
#app/views/images/show.html.erb
<%= @image.attribute %>
<%= form_for [@image, @comment] do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :body %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Of course, you could put this into a `partial`. There are a number of ways to get it working, the above is just the way I'd handle it.

Comment: What's `redirect_to @image if @comment.save` doing in the `show` action of the `ImagesController`?